# ffmpeg atrim not working with shorter video - results in same duration as wav file

Tags: ffmpeg, audio

I have a 16 second video that contains an audio stream and a 4:18 audio file (music). I want to fade the audio and trim it to end at 16 seconds. Here's what I'm trying:

```
ffmpeg -i test.wav -i test.mp4 -y -filter_complex "[0:a]afade=t=out:st=12:d=4:curve=qua[faded];[faded]atrim=0:16,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[aout]" -map 1:v -map "[aout]" -ac 2 test-render.mp4
```

The video renders with no errors and watching the time I see it end at 15.99

```
frame=  480 fps=115 q=-1.0 Lsize=    3992kB time=00:00:15.99 bitrate=2043.9kbits/s speed=3.84x
```

BUT, the resulting video is the duration of the audio file - 4:18.
The audio fades and the video stops right where it is supposed to but freezes at 16 seconds. Here's ffprobe for the resulting video:
[image]

No matter what I've tried I can't seem to figure out how to resolve this.
I'm using ffmpeg 4.4.1

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm stumped.

Comment: Add -report and rerun. Share link to report.

Comment: It looks like there's an issue with the audio file itself. I tried with a different audio file and it rendered a 16 second video as it should have. I rendered an m4a that shows to be 16 seconds in any player, such as the one in Finder. But when I run ffprobe on it I see the duration showing to be 4:18...
`Duration: 00:04:18.35, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 7 kb/s`
Also see that Stream #0:1 contains useless metadata.
`
`Stream #0:1(eng): Data: bin_data (text / 0x74786574)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler`